# Добавить + - font awesome в accordion

Tags: html, jquery

Прошу помощи. Сейчас есть:

```js
$('.item').next().hide();
$('.item').click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
   $('.item').not(this).next().stop(true,true).slideUp();
});
```

```css
  .item {
      background: #eee;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 0 0 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  .hide {
    padding: 10px;
 display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">Блок ссылка 1</div>
    <div class="hide">Скрытый блок 1</div>
    <div class="item">Блок ссылка 2</div>
    <div class="hide">Скрытый блок 2</div>
```

Пользуюсь font awesome. Как добавить сюда toggle fa-plus-circle/fa-minus-circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ну можно как-то так:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    $(this)
      .toggleClass('fa-plus-circle fa-minus-circle')
      .next().slideToggle();


      $('.item')
      .not(this)
        .removeClass('fa-plus-circle')
        .addClass('fa-minus-circle')
        .next().stop(true,true).slideUp();
});
```

Но я бы советовал, присваивать один класс, например open, и манипулировать уже средствами css.

Типа так:

```
$('.item').click(function(){
    $(this)
      .toggleClass('open')
      .next().slideToggle();


      $('.item')
      .not(this)
        .removeClass('open')
        .next().stop(true,true).slideUp();
});
```

Дальше на css

```
.item:before {
    content: "\f055";
}
.item.open:before {
    content: "\f056";
}
```

А этот класс, вам может пригодиться. Если захотите цвет или фон поменять.

Comment: Подскажите, а как первый элемент в этом аккордеоне сделать открытым, если использовать ваш второй пример?

Comment: при загрузки страницы ? если да, то дайте классу item, класс open и стиль  style="display: block" - блоку hide - первому. 
и уберите со скрипта: $('.item').next().hide(); - вне клика - у вас же это стилями задано

Comment: @ЮрийКопоть да, вы правы

Comment: спасибо, получилось